# Different list.phtml for categorys in the backend of Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, list.phtml, magento-2.1.7, category-listing

I try to switch the list.phtml for 4 categorys.
Each category should have his own list.phtml.

**The problem:**

I don't want to call it by the category id directly. I know I can easy do this directly in the list.phtml file for every category.

I want to call it in the **backend** from magento 2.

**product->category under design.**

I used:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list_souvenirs.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

and

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
     <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list_souvenirs.phtml</argument>
     </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

but none of them works.

The theme still use the list.phtml instead of my "list_souvenirs.phtml"

The list.phtml is called in the catalog_category_view.xml like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

Its not a problem with my default.xml because I can delete the "breadcrumbs"  for example.

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update and solution:**

There is a ticket for this problem on github with a solution for fixing it temporary:  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7510#issuecomment-317691277

**Short solution:**

Do not create the

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
```

in the `catalog_category_view.xml`.

Then you can call it in the backend with you're custom *list.phtml* like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
     <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list_yourname.phtml</argument>
     </action>
</referenceBlock>
```